# Call viewDidLayoutSubviews in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode6, autorotate, viewdidlayoutsubviews

I'm trying to implement a control called [SCLAlerView](https://github.com/dogo/SCLAlertView) which enhances Alert messages. But I'm facing a problem when iOS 7 is used (it wotks well on iOS 8). On portrait mode, alert view is shown correctly but in landscape mode or when rotates from portrait to landscape mode, alert view is show wrongly (see images).

[image: Portrait mode]
[image: Landscape mode]

Deeping in code I've seen that on iOS 7 viewDidLayoutSubviews method wasn't called on rotate device.

Has anybody worked with this control on landscape mode and iOS 7? Any idea what's is happening?

Thanks,

Comment: I would imagine the issue is connected to the fact that pre iOS 8 only the first view in the window hierarchy receives rotation events. I.e. any view added to the Window will not autorotate. In iOS 7 I have had to handle this manually by listening for orientation changes and applying a rotation transformation

Comment: Ok. I'll try to add a rotation listener in the viewcontroller.

Comment: I like your library. Thanks for making it!